# play mp3 file as soon as its downloaded

Tags: scripting, wget, mplayer

How do you combine these two different commands into one script:

```
$ wget http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3
#file gets saved as musicfoo.mp3
$ mplayer musicfoo.mp3
```

wget attempts to save the file to disk with the file's default name/extension (as on the internet)...in my case mp3 file...mplayer uses this file as argument to play it.

Any idea how i can combine this to one script?

Comment: I might be wrong, but you -MIGHT- be able to just mplayer the URL and have it play the track. I haven't used mplayer in a while, though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Play file directly

You do not have to even download these files prior to playing them with `mplayer`. From the `mplayer` man page:

*excerpt*

> ```
>   mplayer [options] [file|URL|playlist|-]
> ```

So mplayer can play URLs directly.

#### Example

```
$ mplayer http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3
```

#### Performance

You'll likely need to adjust the cache values to get `mplayer` to playback your content smoothly. There are a few switches to `mplayer` that allows for this.

*excerpt from mplayer man page*

```
-cache <kBytes>
    This option specifies how much memory (in kBytes) to use 
     when precaching a file or URL. Especially useful on slow media.

-cache-min <percentage>
   Playback  will  start when the cache has been filled up to 
   <percentage> of the total.
```

So perhaps something like this, you'll to play with these values to get smooth playbacks for your situation.

```
$ mplayer -cache 8000 -cache-min 30 http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3
```

#### Download and play

Another method discussed in some of the other answers is to use `wget` to download and then play the file. The inherent problem with this approach is getting the file name to play, after the file is done downloading it.

***curl piped to mplayer***

With this approach there are actually 2 techniques within it. The first is to use `wget` or `curl` to start the download and then pipe the data to `mplayer`.

#### Example

```
$ wget http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3 -O - | mplayer -
```

You can also cache the download here as before:

```
$ wget http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3 -O - | mplayer -cache 8192 -
```

***curl 1st, then mplayer***

The other method is to download the file and then play it. You could use a Bash function to wrap this since it now becomes a 2 step process where the file is completely downloaded first, and then played afterwards.

#### Example

```
$ function smplayer() { wget $@ && mplayer $(basename $@); }
```

Then to do a download and play you'd run the function like so:

```
$ smplayer http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3
```

Comment: Yes, however, it doesn't play as a continuous stream.

Comment: @deostroll - can you explain your comment, I don't understand what you mean by a continuous stream.

Comment: downloading happens...when it exceeds a cache limit it starts playing...meanwhile the downloading of the file continues. So it plays until the cache exhausts...then it waits for the cache to fill up...and so on. So I hear a log of intermittent pauses.

Comment: @deostroll - see updates, you'll need to play with the cache switches, this is the drawback to playing back in realtime. You're inability to playback directly is a function of your low bandwidth or the limited bandwidth from the server.

Comment: @deostroll - I've added 2 additional methods, let me know if you need additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wget http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3 && mplayer musicfoo.mp3
```

The `&&` means "once the left side command has *successfully* completed".  This assumes the left side command does not fork or use non-standard [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) values.  I doubt wget does the latter, and as long as you don't use the `-b` switch, it shouldn't do the former either.

Comment: No. The argument to mplayer must be the file wget "creates" while downloading...so technically I don't know the argument to mplayer...hope you get my point...

Comment: If you invoke wget literally as above, the file will be `musicfoo.mp3`.

Comment: I'd want to pass the argument to wget programmatically...hence there is no way for me to determine the name of the file that is going to be downloaded...

Comment: Why didn't you explain this in your question *in the first place* and post the code *you are actually using,* instead of *something that you don't really want to do?*  Anyway, slm may have you covered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mkdir /tmp/download_$$
cd /tmp/download_$$
wget http://mymusic.store.com/musicfoo.mp3
mplayer *
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

```
fpath=$(basename "$1")
wget $1
mplayer $fpath
```

The issue with above is that wget will assign a file name for the downloaded file (appending a `.1` to its end) if the file name already exists. Hence the value of fpath isn't the correct file so to speak.